# Rename NuGet feed

Tags: tfs, nuget

I just renamed a NuGet feed published on TFS 2015 from "Libs" to "Libs_release". Now I want to rename it back to "Libs", but I cannot. The (unfortunately german) error message is:

> Der Feedname "Libs" wird bald verfügbar sein.

What can I do? Do I have to wait a certain time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it takes some time that the name can be reused. After ~2 hours I was able to rename the feed back to Libs.